# How To Set Up Timer In C++?

Tags: c++, timer

I'm new to C++ and currently I'm using Code::Blocks to run my code. So, I wonder if i can set up timer until a code is executed because i need timer to make my program looks better. Any answers is accepted ^^

Comment: "i need timer to make my program looks better" -- what exactly do you mean by *timer*?

Comment: Show us what you've done till now. A simple Google search should've given you some results about `system time`, `start` and `stop`.

Comment: I'm sorry that i dont have the code right now, my laptop is broken so i need to repair it for a week and i got no files about code::blocks...so basically, i just want to know if there is timer function in c++

Comment: *So, I wonder if i can set up timer until a code is executed because i need timer to make my program looks better* It's not clear to me what you mean by that.

Comment: in my previous program, i want the user to put his biodata, and at the end i want to show a table...before the table i put this sentence "Your Biodata Will Be Shown", so before showing the table, i want the program to pause or wait for a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a timer class long ago. You can find the complete code on `Github` here: [timer](https://github.com/activatedgeek/timer)

It is a complete example with `Makefile` as well.

**Note**: You will need the ability to compile `C++11`.

Comment: You should better to use constructor and destructor . So you need only one line in any functions. However this might be more flexible in some situations.

Comment: @user1436187 I tried to add flexibility and tried to handle any unwanted basic situations like starting a timer twice. Still this code is 3 years old but relevant enough for a starting point. I have improved now :).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for this purpose. In constructor and destructor get the current time. You only need to subtracts them to get the elapse time of each functions including `main`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono